# Can't activate Cortana in some languages

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I'm having trouble enabling Cortana. At first it worked fine with en-UK, but since it wasn't recognizing my voice very well, I tried to switch it to en-US, by following the instructions. So I changed the region:

[image]

And the speech language:

[image]

But it doesn't work. I tried to repeat the operation with France and French, doesn't work either. In both cases, I have a "Cortana isn't supported in the region and language you selected" error in the configuration menu.

What am I forgetting here?

Comment: Does it work if you put it back in en-uk again ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue came from languages packs not being installed properly – it was hinted at by the fact that only en-UK could be used as a display language, and when investigated further, I realized that this was due to an override feature that prevented the other languages from being downloaded, and thus used as Windows (or Cortana) display language.

More info [here (see answer by Morgan Simonsen).](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a6854f04-0802-4dac-83f9-68c3a3e2de3c/unable-to-add-additional-display-language?forum=w8itproinstall)